# Decode a web page using request and BeautifulSoup package

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying a practice question of python. The question is "Use the BeautifulSoup and requests Python packages to print out a list of all the article titles on the New York Times homepage." 
Below is my solution but it doesn't give any output. I am using Jupyter Notebook and when I run the below code it does nothing. My kernel is also working properly which means I have a problem with my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url= 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
r=requests.get(base_url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(base_url))

get_titles=soup.find_all(class_="css-1vctqli esl82me2" )

print()
for title in get_titles:
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get that class tag ? This is not the right one.

You need to replace `css-1vctqli esl82me2` by `css-1j836f9 esl82me3`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(base_url))

get_titles = soup.find_all(class_ = "css-1j836f9 esl82me3")

print()
for title in get_titles:
    print(title.text)
```

And the output :

[image]

Comment: How did you find the class tag? I came across that tag through inspect element of NY Times.

Comment: Did the same thing but I didn't even found yours. http://snpy.in/A3iX7b

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It worked. I must have done something else while searching for the class tag.