# Decoding a web page with BeautifulSoup and requests

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My first time ever trying this, so be gentle ... :-)

Following this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117047/decode-a-web-page-using-request-and-beautifulsoup-package
```

I am using the accepted answer as my base.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(base_url), features="lxml")

get_titles = soup.find_all(class_="css-6n7j50")

print()
for title in get_titles:
    print(title.text)
```

I can see two items in soup in the debugger:
[image]

But nothing prints.

All I want to do is extract the titles from the base_url, format and print them.

Comment: Doesn't look like the right class for me. It is possible the classes are dynamically re-arranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it's printing empty string is that when you are running

```
for title in get_titles:
    print(title.text)
```

The object of the title doesn't have text in it.
The text attribute is returning the value that in the inner HTML of the tags and in the title object there only attributes of the tags.

Comment: you can use print(title) to get all the tags <div class="css-6n7j50"><button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Sections Navigation &amp; Search" class="er09x8g1 css-1uqx5yl" data-testid="nav-button"><svg class="css-1fe7a5q" viewbox="0 0 16 16"><rect fill="#333" height="2" width="14" x="1" y="3"></rect><rect fill="#333" height="2" width="14" x="1" y="7"></rect><rect fill="#333" height="2" width="14" x="1" y="11"></rect></svg></button></div> and from that parse the relevant part that you need